# What does this typedef and conversion operator syntax mean?

Tags: c++

I've run across a class which wraps a `boost::shared_ptr` and am having trouble understanding what the conversion operator does and how it works specifically. The class:

```
class TestWrapper {
public:
    explicit TestWrapper(int* ptr) : internal(ptr) {}


    typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> TestWrapper::* safe_bool;

    boost::shared_ptr<int> internal;

    bool operator!() { return !internal; }
    operator safe_bool() const { return internal ? &TestWrapper::internal : 0; }
};
```

The code makes tests like the following work as if they were testing the `null`ness of the wrapped pointer like so:

```
TestWrapper t(new int(5));

if(!t) {
    std::cout << "!null" << std::endl;
}

if(t) {
    std::cout << "null" << std::endl;
}
```

However, I've been unable to wrap my head around what the typedef means:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<int> TestWrapper::* safe_bool;
```

It doesn't look like a rename of `boost::shared_ptr`, it doesn't look like a function pointer (which requires parentheses?). What is it?

I also can't figure out what the conversion operator means:

```
operator safe_bool() const { return internal ? &TestWrapper::internal : 0; }
```

What is `&TestWrapper::internal`? Why is it the same type as the `typedef`? Why can 0 be converted to it?

Comment: Member function pointer.   C++ library programmers do have to use heroic syntax to avoid the pointer-to-bool implicit conversion design mistake.  Something you'd never do yourself, until you get enough "your code sucks" bug reports.  The boost people are pretty heroic.

Comment: See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool. In C++11, there is `explicit operator bool()`, so this trick is no longer needed.

Comment: The conversion operator acts like `operator bool()`, so that `if(t)` works. But `operator bool()` would also allow other things like implicit conversion of a `TestWrapper` to `int`. So the data member pointer type `safe_bool` is used instead because it can be used in an `if`, but nothing else. (No implicit conversion, no `<` comparison, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boost::shared_ptr<int> TestWrapper::*
```

This is a class data member pointer. It points to a data member from class `TestWrapper` of type `boost::shared_ptr<int>`

Let's give a simpler example with class data member pointers:

```
int X::*
```

This is a class data member pointer to a data member of type `int` in a class `X` so for instance you can do:

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
};

struct Y
{
    int a;
};

auto test()
{
    using T = int X::*; // a pointer to an int data member of class X

    X x1{1, 2};
    X x2{100, 200};

    T pa = &X::a;       // pointer to data member a of class X
    T pb = &X::b;       // pointer to data member b of class X

    T pc = &X::c;  // illegal
    T py = &Y::a;  // illegal

    std::cout << x1.*pa; // 1
    std::cout << x1.*pb; // 2

    std::cout << x2.*pa; // 100
    std::cout << x2.*pb; // 200

}
```

---

```
operator safe_bool() const
```

This is a conversion operator to the mentioned class data member pointer type.

> What is `&TestWrapper::internal`

Is the address of the data member `internal` of the class `TestWrapper`

> Why is it the same type as the typedef

Because internal is a class data member of type `boost::shared_ptr<int>` of class `TestWrapper`

> Why can 0 be converted to it

Being a pointer, you can assign `nullptr` to it. Or, as the code does, you can assign `0` to it. This operator returns a pointer to the data member `internal` only if `(bool) internal != false`, else it returns the null pointer.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Been writing C++ for 13 years and have never seen the pointer to data member syntax before. Makes so much more sense now.